# How to orderBy before sum

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
competitions (id, ...)
questions (id, ...)
teams (id, ...)
team_user (id, user_id, team_id, ...)
answer_user (user_id, competition_id, question_id, points, ...)
```

I am trying to build a query to list all teams who participated in the competition id = 20, given that we sort the list based on accumulation of the teams' users' points.  However, sometimes 2 teams receive the same total points, so we need to show the team who was able to reach that total of points first in the list before others (based on the answers created_at column)

I am able to get this list using the following query, but not able to sort based on answer_user created_at column:

```
$ranks = Team::withCount(['answers' => function ($q) use ($competition_id) {   
        $q->where('competition_id', $competition_id)
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(points)'));
    }])
    ->where('competition_id', $competition_id)
    ->orderBy('answers_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

**Edit 1**
I can achieve the sort required when I replace the

```
->select(DB::raw('sum(points)')
```

with

```
->select(DB::raw('max(answer_user.created_at)')
```

However, I want actually both aggregations to work.  Basically, finding the total points each team scored, then sort them based on the time, first to score is the one show first.

Comment: Does your teams table contain the ```competition_id``` columns?

Comment: You can use multiple sortBy's to achieve this effect https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/11

Comment: @greed chikara, yes it does

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `sortBy()` or `sortByDesc()` function after `get()`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortbydesc

```
    $ranks = Team::withCount(['answers'=>function($q) use($competition_id){         
                $q->where('competition_id',$competition_id)->select(DB::raw('sum(points)'));
}])->where('competition_id',$competition_id)->get()->sortByDesc('answer_user');
```

Comment: The current query doesn't have access to ```answer_user```, therefore it won't be able to sort it by it.

Comment: Try this `->sortByDesc('answers.answer_user ');`

Comment: ```withCount``` doesn't load the relationship, it only gives the count.

Comment: I tried both sortBy & sortByDesc and both returns the same list, when each should actually return the list in different order

Comment: I agree @greedchikara, but there should be a way to access the relationship for sorting, just like we did for SUM with withCount

Comment: what I could make out of your table schema I would suggest something like the below query ```Team::selectRaw("teams.id, sum(answer_user.points), answer_user.created_at")->join('team_user', function($join) {
 $join->on('team_user.team_id', '=', 'teams.id');
})->join('answer_user', function($join) use($competition_id) {
 $join->on('answer_user.user_id', '=', 'team_user.user_id')->where('answer_user.competition_id', '=', $competition_id);})->where('competition_id',$competition_id)->groupBy('teams.id')->orderBy('answers_count', 'desc')->orderBy('answer_user.created_at', 'desc')
->get();```